# Change color for default blue location marker

Tags: android, google-maps

It is possible to set My own colors for a blue location marker and an accuracy circle?
For example, I need to use the orange palett for this.
Thanks!

[image: Google map and blue dot]

Answer (score 3):

Use you custom Image for marker

you can use following code to set custom marker

**FIRST METHOD:**

```
int height = 100;
    int width = 80;
    BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) 
    ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.current_loc_marker);
    Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
    Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker));
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

**SECOND METHOD :**

This is how to make a default marker

```
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(MELBOURNE)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

and these are the constants you can use

float   HUE_AZURE
float   HUE_BLUE
float   HUE_CYAN
float   HUE_GREEN
float   HUE_MAGENTA 
float   HUE_ORANGE
float   HUE_RED 
float   HUE_ROSE
float   HUE_VIOLET
float   HUE_YELLOW

**THIRD METHOD:**

```
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(MELBOURNE)
.icon(getMarkerIcon("#ff2299")));

public BitmapDescriptor getMarkerIcon(String color) {
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(Color.parseColor(color), hsv);
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(hsv[0]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried this approach, but it doesn't look elegant. I want to colorize a **standard blue marker.**

Comment: there are may other optional color present in google map marker option.
you can use one of them'